# Read a RAID device directly using read(2)

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I have create a Linux Software RAID, with chunk size 4096B, and 4 disks.
Then, I'm trying to do write and read test on the RAID, say /dev/md0.

The following code is read test and BLOCK_SIZE is the amount I want to read. However, whenever I set it not power of 2, such as 3*4096, I will get an error after read, saying "Invalid Argument". And it is the same case with write.

As far as I can understand, read(2) and write(2) should be able to perform operation on any amount of bytes the user wants, so please help me with it and the code.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define BLOCK_SIZE 8*4096 //bytes
#define BUFF_OFFSET 8*4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char device[64];
    int fd;   
    void *buff;
    int size; //bytes
    int seek;

    fd = open(argv[1], O_DIRECT | O_RSYNC | O_RDONLY);

    posix_memalign(&buff, BUFF_OFFSET, BLOCK_SIZE);

    int load;
    seek = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    load = read(fd,buff,BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (load < 0){
        printf("Cannot read\n");
        perror("because");
        break;
    }
    else{
        printf("%d\n",load);
    }    
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the man pages (open and read), including the errors section.

Comment: @Mat I've viewed that, the error code is EINVAL, but there is a lot possibilities for EINVAL, the most possible I think is the file is not aligned or the buffer is not aligned. But I have no idea why not aligned

Comment: You're using O_DIRECT. Read the `open` man page, and search for that flag.

Comment: @Mat, It says " Under Linux 2.4, transfer sizes, and the alignment of the user buffer and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block size of the filesystem.  Since Linux 2.6.0, alignment to the logical block size of the underlying storage (typically 512 bytes) suffices." I used "blockdev --getss" and found out the logical block size for /dev/md0 is 512